# HTML table does not display value from ArrayList

Tags: java, html, jsp, arraylist

I want to display a table by retrieving values from an Arraylist in my JSP. This is the table section of the code from the JSP

```
<p> 
<table id="myTable">                                    
    <tr class="header">
        <%                          
            ArrayList arrColHead = new ArrayList();
            arrColHead.add("Col Head 1");
            rrColHead.add("Col Head 2");
            for(int i=0; i < arrColHead.size(); i++)
            {   
                %>
                    <th style="width:10%">
                    <% 
                    arrColHead.get(i);
                    %>
                    </th>
                <%
            }
        %>
    </tr>                                     
</table>
```

This does not display "Col Head 1" and "Col Head 2". What could possibly be wrong?

However, if I try to hard code the values, it shows the table properly.

```
for(int i=0; i < arrColHead.size(); i++)
{   
    %>
        <th style="width:10%">
        Col Head 1
        </th>
    <%
```

}

I am new to J2EE programming. So any help here is appreciated

Comment: use `<%=` when displaying to the page. But using scriptlets is really frowned upon. (Also not of this time. It's reaaallllyyy old). Please use jstl (and expression language, EL) if you want to use java EE.

Comment: Use this way <% = arrColHead.get(i);  %>

Answer (score 2):

Try `<%= arrColHead.get(i) %>` OR `out.println(arrColHead.get(i));`

Answer (score 0):

Check it might be simple issue.

```
ArrayList arrColHead = new ArrayList();
        arrColHead.add("Col Head 1");
        rrColHead.add("Col Head 2");
```

in second add it should be

```
arrColHead.add("Col Head 2");
```

not

```
rrColHead.add("Col Head 2");
```

Just check.